# Why won't my snake game load at all?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make sure that something appears in my browser as I make this snake game but nothing's showing up.  I looked over it a bunch of times & can't figure out what I did wrong.  Right now if I refresh the browser, the screen is completely blank.

gameTime.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WOMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

gameTime.js

```
    // constants
var COLS = 26, ROWS = 26;

// IDs
var EMPTY = 0, SNAKE = 1, FRUIT = 2;

// Directions
var LEFT = 0, UP, = 1, RIGHT = 2, DOWN = 3;

var grid = {
    width: null,
    height: null,
    _grid: null,

    init: function(d, c, r) {
        this.width = c;
        this.height = r;

        this._grid = [];

        for(var x = 0; x < c; x++) {
            this._grid.push([]); // push an empty array 
            for(var y = 0; y < r; y++) {
                this._grid[x].push(d); // push values into each row for the column
            }
        }
    },

    set: function(val, x, y) {
        this._grid[x][y] = val; // 
    },

    get: function(x, y) {
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
}

var snake = {
    direction: null,
    last: null;
    _queue: null,

    init: function(d, x, y) {
        this.direction = d;

        this._queue = [];

        this.insert(x, y);
    },

    insert: function(x, y) {
        this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y})
        this.last - this._queue[0];
    }

    remove: function() {
        return this._queue.pop();
    }
}

function setFood() {
    var empty = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            if(grid.get(x,y) == EMPTY) {
                empty.push({x:x, y:y})
            }
        }
    }
    var randpos = empty[Math.floor(Math.random() * empty.length)];
    grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

// Game objects

var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames;

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS*20;
    canvas.height = ROWS*20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    frames = 0;
    keystate = {}; // empty object

    init();
    loop();
}

function init() {
    grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

    var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
    snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
    grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

    setFood();
}

function loop() {
    update();
    draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function update() {
    frames++;
}

    function draw() {
        var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
        var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

        for(var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
            for(var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
                switch(grid.get(x, y)) {
                    case EMPTY:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    break;
                    case SNAKE:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                    break;
                    case FRUIT:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                    break;
                }
                ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
            }
        }
    }

    main();
```

Comment: Please review your code with more attention. For example, in the Directions, you should write ``UP = 1,`` and not ``UP, = 1``. You can use your browser console to check for syntax errors (usually <kbd>F12</kbd> on keyboard).

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code, I'd suggest going through them all. I used http://jshint.com/. https://gist.github.com/TristanWiley/54e81e2fbeafbc41b9894abdbb145034

Comment: @André I fixed that error by checking the console like you said, and one other syntax error as well but my screen is still blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of styling issues. You have commas in the wrong places. The easiest way to debug this is to fix your code, go into developer tools and look at the console log for errors. Also your js file should be placed at the end of your file as to let the DOM load first.

var COLS = 26, ROWS = 26;

```
// IDs
var EMPTY = 0, SNAKE = 1, FRUIT = 2;

// Directions
var LEFT = 0, UP = 1, RIGHT = 2, DOWN = 3;

var grid = {
    width: null,
    height: null,
    _grid: null,

    init: function (d, c, r) {
        this.width = c;
        this.height = r;

        this._grid = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < c; x++) {
            this._grid.push([]); // push an empty array 
            for (var y = 0; y < r; y++) {
                this._grid[x].push(d); // push values into each row for the column
            }
        }
    },

    set: function (val, x, y) {
        this._grid[x][y] = val; // 
    },

    get: function (x, y) {
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
}

var snake = {
    direction: null,
    last: null,
    _queue: null,

    init: function (d, x, y) {
        this.direction = d;

        this._queue = [];

        this.insert(x, y);
    },

    insert: function (x, y) {
        this._queue.unshift({ x: x, y: y })
        this.last - this._queue[0];
    },

    remove: function () {
        return this._queue.pop();
    }
}


function setFood() {
    var empty = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            if (grid.get(x, y) == EMPTY) {
                empty.push({ x: x, y: y })
            }
        }
    }
    var randpos = empty[Math.floor(Math.random() * empty.length)];
    grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

// Game objects

var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames;

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS * 20;
    canvas.height = ROWS * 20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.getElementById("game").appendChild(canvas);

    frames = 0;
    keystate = {}; // empty object

    init();
    loop();
}

function init() {
    grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

    var sp = { x: Math.floor(COLS / 2), y: ROWS - 1 };
    snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
    grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

    setFood();
}

function loop() {
    update();
    draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function update() {
    frames++;
}

function draw() {
    var tw = canvas.width / grid.width;
    var th = canvas.height / grid.height;

    for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
                case EMPTY:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    break;
                case SNAKE:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                    break;
                case FRUIT:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                    break;
            }
            ctx.fillRect(x * tw, y * th, tw, th);
        }
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: According to my console, it says I have an error on the line with `remove: function ()`.  The error says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.  But how?  That's written perfectly to my knowledge.

Comment: Because your remove function should have a comma after the bracket above it, for separating the insert function.

Comment: That was the problem!  Thank you so much :D  and my apologies for the confusion.

Comment: No worries. Keep programming!

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your script for you. To highlight your issues:

- Your **insert** method inside your **snake** object needed a comma to separate it from the **remove** method.
- Your **last** property in your **snake** object needs a comma to separate it from other properties. You have a semicolon.
- Your **Up** variable has a comma after it. Remove it.

This code runs for me:

```
<script>

   // constants
var COLS = 26, ROWS = 26;

// IDs
var EMPTY = 0, SNAKE = 1, FRUIT = 2;

// Directions
var LEFT = 0, UP = 1, RIGHT = 2, DOWN = 3;

var grid = {
    width: null,
    height: null,
    _grid: null,

    init: function(d, c, r) {
        this.width = c;
        this.height = r;

        this._grid = [];

        for(var x = 0; x < c; x++) {
            this._grid.push([]); // push an empty array 
            for(var y = 0; y < r; y++) {
                this._grid[x].push(d); // push values into each row for the column
            }
        }
    },

    set: function(val, x, y) {
        this._grid[x][y] = val; // 
    },

    get: function(x, y) {
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
}

var snake = {
    direction: null,
    last: null,
    _queue: null,

    init: function(d, x, y) {
        this.direction = d;

        this._queue = [];

        this.insert(x, y);
    },

    insert: function(x, y) {
        this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y})
        this.last - this._queue[0];
    },

    remove: function() {
        return this._queue.pop();
    }
}

function setFood() {
    var empty = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            if(grid.get(x,y) == EMPTY) {
                empty.push({x:x, y:y})
            }
        }
    }
    var randpos = empty[Math.floor(Math.random() * empty.length)];
    grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

// Game objects

var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames;

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS*20;
    canvas.height = ROWS*20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    frames = 0;
    keystate = {}; // empty object

    init();
    loop();
}

function init() {
    grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

    var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
    snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
    grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

    setFood();
}

function loop() {
    update();
    draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function update() {
    frames++;
}

    function draw() {
        var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
        var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

        for(var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
            for(var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
                switch(grid.get(x, y)) {
                    case EMPTY:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    break;
                    case SNAKE:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                    break;
                    case FRUIT:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                    break;
                }
                ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
            }
        }
    }

    main(); 

</script>
```